# I Need calculated value from string set

Tags: sql-server

How I can get value from character string? for example i have stored value in a table

```
Field | Value 
-------------
A1   | '1 +  2'
A2   | '1 *  2'
```

i need a select query the result should be as follows

```
A1  -- 3
A2  -- 2
```

I wrote

```
SELECT Field,Value from Table
```

result become

```
A1 -- 1 + 2
A2 -- 1 * 2
```

Comment: Don't try to evaluate an expression from a string in the database. That is not what it is made to do. You could with dynamic sql probably, but it is not the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't recommend you do this. This is not a good practice for a RDBMS.

As others pointed out, you can split off the first val, the second val, and the operator. This works as long as there is a space between the val and the operator. If they all three get mashed together, you would have to write this instead with a patindex.

```
DECLARE @val1 VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @val2 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @operator VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @string1 VARCHAR(100) = '1 +  2'
DECLARE @string2 VARCHAR(100) = '1 *  2'
DECLARE @string3 VARCHAR(100) = '4 / 2'
DECLARE @string4 VARCHAR(100) = '234 + 3245'
DECLARE @string5 VARCHAR(100) = '90 % 10'

SET @val1  = LTRIM(RTRIM((SUBSTRING(@string1, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @string1, 0)))))
SET @val2 = LTRIM(RTRIM((REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@string1), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@string1), 0))))))
SET @operator = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string1, @val1, ''), @val2, '')))
DECLARE @sql1 NVARCHAR(100) = 'SELECT ' + @val1 + @operator + @val2

SET @val1  = LTRIM(RTRIM((SUBSTRING(@string2, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @string2, 0)))))
SET @val2 = LTRIM(RTRIM((REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@string2), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@string2), 0))))))
SET @operator = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string2, @val1, ''), @val2, '')))
DECLARE @sql2 NVARCHAR(100) = 'SELECT ' + @val1 + @operator + @val2


SET @val1  = LTRIM(RTRIM((SUBSTRING(@string3, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @string3, 0)))))
SET @val2 = LTRIM(RTRIM((REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@string3), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@string3), 0))))))
SET @operator = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string3, @val1, ''), @val2, '')))
DECLARE @sql3 NVARCHAR(100) = 'SELECT ' + @val1 + @operator + @val2


SET @val1  = LTRIM(RTRIM((SUBSTRING(@string4, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @string4, 0)))))
SET @val2 = LTRIM(RTRIM((REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@string4), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@string4), 0))))))
SET @operator = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string4, @val1, ''), @val2, '')))
DECLARE @sql4 NVARCHAR(100) = 'SELECT ' + @val1 + @operator + @val2


SET @val1  = LTRIM(RTRIM((SUBSTRING(@string5, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @string5, 0)))))
SET @val2 = LTRIM(RTRIM((REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@string5), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@string5), 0))))))
SET @operator = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string5, @val1, ''), @val2, '')))
DECLARE @sql5 NVARCHAR(100) = 'SELECT ' + @val1 + @operator + @val2

print @sql1
EXEC sp_executesql @sql1
print @sql2
EXEC sp_executesql @sql2
print @sql3
EXEC sp_executesql @sql3
print @sql4
EXEC sp_executesql @sql4
print @sql5
EXEC sp_executesql @sql5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the value column by the mathematical operator + or * and then check what you got if it is a numeric value. Then use what you have to do the actual operation.

You can use the function STRING_SPLIT to do the split

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom function to parse the character string casting each numeric value and choosing operators.

Answer (score 0):

As you know by now, SQL Server does not have an EVAL() funtction.  However, with a little dynamic SQL, it is possible, but really not recommended.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Field] varchar(50),[Value] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('A1','1 + 2')
,('A2','1 * 2')
,('A3','datediff(DAY,''2018-01-01'',getdate())')  -- Added Just for Fun

Declare @SQL varchar(max)
Select @SQL = Stuff((Select ',' +S 
 From (Select S=concat('(''',[Field],''',',[Value],')') From  @YourTable ) A
 For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')

Exec('Select * from (values ' + @SQL + ')A([Field],[Value])')
```

**Returns**

```
Field   Value
A1      3
A2      2
A3      164
```